environmental variables accessing in backend files
The following is the tree structure of the files file tree
This is code with error :
mailtrap.config.js
import { MailtrapClient } from "mailtrap";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN_MAILTRAP;
const ENDPOINT = process.env.ENDPOINT_MAILTRAP;
// making dynamic client and sender from the db(sender will be from the mailtrap and the user is from the user email from the DB)
export const mailtrapClient = new MailtrapClient({
  endpoint: ENDPOINT,
  token: TOKEN,
});
export const sender = {
  email: "mailtrap@demomailtrap.com",
  name: "Mailtrap Test",
};


I am able to access the TOKEN_MAILTRAP , ENDPOINT_MAILTRAP from the .env file in the mailtrap directory but cannot access them from the root directory
complete backend directory
Here is the problem :
i can run the generateTokenAndSetCookie.js file with the root directory .env file
generateTokenAndSetCookie.js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
const generateTokenAndSetCookie = (res,userId)=>{
    // token
    const token = jwt.sign({userId},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
        expiresIn:"7d"
    });
    // setting cookie in the response
    res.cookie("token",token,{
        httpOnly:true,
        secure:process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        sameSite:"strict",
        maxAge:7*24*60*60*1000,
    });
    return token;
}
export default generateTokenAndSetCookie;

Is there any errors in the code of mailtrap.config.js
In generateTokenAndSetCookie.js the file can access the environmental variables of root directory but in mailtrap.config.js it cannot access the environmental varibales of root directory but can access the environmental variables of mailtrap directory
it came undefined when i console log the environment variables from the root directory

Please see the dotenv() docs regarding ES6 imports - https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv?tab=readme-ov-file#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

According to dotenv documentation , by default, when you call dotenv.config() without any parameters, "config will look for a file called .env in the current working directory."
If you want to access both env file /api/mailtrap/.env and /.env, You have to replace dotenv.config() in line 3, mailtrap.config.js, with dotenv.config({ path: ['../../.env', './.env'] }).
mailtrap.config.js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: ['../../.env', './.env'] });
...

